# 2 dimensional array in struct

Tags: c

I have to implement game of life, it is almost complete, the last thing I want to do is to allocate my field dynamical. I'm working under Windows, got no Valgrind and I don't no what's the error in my code. Eclipse shows only that the process is not functional anymore.

Can anyone tell me, what's the problem in my code? Or maybe I don't need a 2 dim. array for game of life field?

```
struct game_field  {
    int length;
    int **field;
};


static struct game_field *new_game_field(unsigned int l) {
    struct game_field *pstField;
    pstField = calloc(1, sizeof(struct game_field));
    pstField->length = l;
    pstField->field = malloc(l * sizeof(int*));
    for( int i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        pstField->field[i] = malloc(l * sizeof(int));
        if(NULL == pstField->field[i]) {
             printf("No memory for line %d\n",i);
        }
    }
    return pstField;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of memory checking just *one* of three memory allocations? Have you checked that calloc or the first malloc isn't returning NULL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079262/conwayss-game-of-life-array-problems

Comment: There's not necessarily any thought to that, I could check for null also the other allocations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think a little bit about the structures and what you are storing.

For the game of life you need to know the state of the cell on the board which is indicated by and integer so your struct should become:

```
struct game_field  {
   int length;
   int *field;
};
```

And once you know the dimensions of the field you should allocate it once:

```
struct game_field *gf = calloc(1, sizeof(struct game_field));
gf->length = <blah>;
gf->field = malloc(gf->length*gf->length*sizeof(int));
```

This way you have an array of integers that you can use as your board.

Comment: Except you can't access that using 2D array notation. You'd need to say `gf->field[x*hdim+y]`.

Comment: Hm, I don't get that notation. Is it like: *(pstField->field+i*pstField->length+j) or how? Or what's the "x" ?

Comment: @ams that's true but you can do `gf->field2d = (int **)gf->field;` and you have your 2d representation.

Comment: @Michael The 2d arrays are stored in memory as a [contiguous space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) so in order to access element in row x column y in that representation you will need to do it as ams pointed out except instead of `hdim` you will use `length`

Comment: @Michael: Ok, but at least tell us what was the problem, if it wasn't the allocation?

Comment: @Karlson: no, I don't think casting an int* to an int** is going to make anything 2D. 2D arrays with pointers just don't work the same as statically declared arrays. In the one case the compiler does a double indirection, whereas in the other it uses knowledge of the row/column size to do pointer arithmetic. If you use malloc to create your own field as one block then you need to do the arithmetic yourself, as I showed.

Comment: @michael: I presume you figured it out already, but the 'x' and 'y' are just the gmae-field co-ordinates.

Comment: I had to access the elements through the method of the first comment. I had it in a way it doesn't output anything. And @ams yeah, i figured it out, thank you! Sry if the topic went a little in an other direction, I only wanted to get my game of life field dynamical. Prior to this I had the 2 dynamical array constant.. and I just thought I allocate it

Comment: @Karlson +1 for (nearly) the most efficient answer to the question though. (It could be improved one step more by declaring field as `int field[0]` and then allocating the space as `gf = malloc (sizeof(game_field)+length*length*sizeof(int))` (i.e. overallocate the struct size) but that's slightly evil. ;)

Comment: @ams That's not evil but I think that OP's teacher(s) (somehow I think it's homework) will question how he came by this knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first `malloc` should be:

```
pstField->field = malloc(l * sizeof(int*));
```

Your array is `int**`, so the first level of allocation is an `int*`.

**Edit**: Well, I've tested your code and it does not crash for me. The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forget that - thanks, but the main problem persists

Comment: @Michael: are you sure you have isolated the problem to this piece of code?

Comment: Hm I don't think so, but Karlson's idea is maybe a good one ;)

Comment: Hmmm... have you tried casting the result of malloc to int** and int* respectively?

Comment: Well I've copied your code and tried it and for me it works. What value are you using for l?

Comment: Well, then maybe the problem is somewhere else, because I've tested with exactly the same parameters and it does not crash for me.

Comment: You are right, it does not crash, there is anywhere else an error. The allocation works just fine.. hm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of your code that allocates the field in one block, but still lets you use array brackets for both dimensions:

```
struct game_field {
  int   length;
  int **field;
};

static struct game_field *new_game_field(unsigned int len)
{
  struct game_field *pstField;
  pstField = malloc(sizeof(struct game_field));
  pstField->length = len;

  /* allocate enough space for all the row pointers + the row contents */
  pstField->field = malloc((len * sizeof(int *)) + (len * len * sizeof(int)));

  /* point the row pointers (at the start of the block) at the row contents
   * (further into the block). */
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    pstField->field[i] = (int *)(&field[len]) + (i * len);

  return pstField;
}
```

This way you can free the field in one shot:

```
void free_game_field(struct game_field *gf)
{
  free(gf->field);
  free(gf);
}
```

And you can keep the bracket notation to access the elements:

```
int row7col3 = gf->field[7][3];
```

Note that what you have (here as well as in your original code) is not exactly a two-dimensional array, but an array of pointers to arrays of integers 
(there is a difference, but the `arr[x][y]` notation can work for either one).